# AngularJS - Include <script> after all directives have rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Apologies if this is an old question. I have spent a few hours searching for an answer but had no luck.

I'm attempting to convert an existing (primarily jQuery) application to use AngularJS.  I've hit a problem where a JavaScript file I am including in index.html is being run too early when being included in my AngularJS application. i.e. by using a `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/js/theme.js"></script>
```

This file contains a lot of jQuery which needs the rest of the page to have been rendered to have an effect.  So is there a way I can include this script and ensure it is only loaded after the rest of the page has finished loading?  I have a set of directives on the page and the script is being loaded before these are rendered.

Update:

Here is the structure of my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>App Title</title>
<base href="/">

<!--  icons and CSS -->
<link href="/img/ico/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"
    type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css">

<!-- External Libraries -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/external/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/external/angular/angular.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Components -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/services/ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/components/navigation/js/navigation.js"></script>

<!-- App set and config -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app/routes.js"></script>
<!--  endbuild -->

<!--  Precompiled HTML templates -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/templates.module.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-cloak>     
    <!-- directive -->
    <top-nav-bar></top-nav-bar>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- directive -->
            <side-nav-bar></side-nav-bar>

            <!-- angular view -->
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- directive -->
    <adysis-footer></adysis-footer>

    <!-- Bootstrapper -->
    <script src='/js/app.bootstrap.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT FILE WHICH NEEDS TO RUN AFTER PAGE HAS LOADED! -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/components/js/theme.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the "theme.js" file is the last item of the `<body>`.  I have stopped in the file to ensure it is being loaded.  But this is always done before the rest of the page has rendered.  Could some other JavaScript be interfering upsetting things?  Note that I have not included all of the JavaScript files that are being included.

Update 2:

I've added further break points in the JavaScript functions for the directives you can see in my index.html.  Each of them is stopped in after the theme.js is executed.  I don't know why this is, so I'm mentioning this in case it gives more clues as to the problem.

Update 3:

The first line of the "theme.js" file is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
```

And then the function contains a long series of jQuery selectors to setup events and so on.  My understanding is the point of this line is to wait until the document has been loaded.  But could something in my setup, e.g. Angular, be preventing this from happening?

I've tried changing this line to:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function($)
```

and whilst this does lead to the content on the function to be run later, it's still not after the whole document has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure it's at the end of your HTML Body and not in the header section. If it's in the head section it'll load before the page renders.

Comment: Thanks for that.  However I had already tried that and it made no difference.  I'll add an overview of my index.html to see if that might give any further clues as to why it is going wrong.  Many thanks for any further help ....

Comment: @eebsie  Try adding defer as an attribute to your script call? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp